# MVC Imageresizer show empty image

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, imageresizer

I have mvc 5 project that use imageresizer for crop and resize images, on local it work file but in server , when i set query end of image address , result is empty image

For exmaple :

[Original](http://avvalkhabar.ir/Upload/App/channel_7.jpg)
[image]

[With query](http://avvalkhabar.ir/Upload/App/channel_7.jpg?width=100&height=100&mode=crop)
[image]

Comment: there is no code , imageresizer make changes on image with query in the path , i put examples

Comment: You have grant read and write access images folder?

Comment: @MuhammadSaqlain How should I do it?

Comment: First of all go to your web.config and set 



<system.web>
        <customErrors mode="Off"/>
</system.web>

In your web.config file

Comment: @MuhammadSaqlain i do this, but still show empty and do not display any error

Comment: Access to the path 'C:\Inetpub\vhosts\avvalkhabar.ir\httpdocs\imagecache\17cd' is denied.

Comment: This is exception. You need to grant access to your folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ImageResizer's DiskCache plugin requires read/write/delete permissions to the cache folder on disk.

The ASP.NET (the Application Pool user account) needs NTFS read/write/delete permissions to the application directory and ~/imagecache folder.

The IIS user account (often NETWORK SERVICE) needs at minimum read permissions to the application directory and ~/imagecache folder.